# Why does angular2-webpack-starter work with:' localhost:3000/#/', but Not with 'https://hostname/front/#/' WHY?

Tags: nginx, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, starter-kits

I am using the 'angular2-webpack-stater' project and am ready to integrate with with my back end server.  I setup nginx with two proxy-passes to connect to the front-end and the back-end:

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name xxxxxxxxx.com;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; 
          includeSubdomains";
    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex off;
    rewrite_log on;

  location ^~ /server/ {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  location ^~ /front/ {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
...
}
```

The back-end works as expected.  And when I run the front-end with 'npm run server', the browser opens at 'localhost:3000/#/' and all works as expected.

BUT when I attempt to access the frontend with:

```
https://xxxxxxx.com/front/#/
```

(instead of using localhost:3000/#/) I see:

```
<% if (webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags) { %> <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %> <% } %> Loading... <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.isDevServer && htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.HMR !== true) { %> <% } %>
```

because there is an error when attempting the GET of:

```
https://xxxxxxx.com/webpack-dev-server.js
```

from the index.html file.  This fails at: `<script src="/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>` since it cannot locate the webpack-dev-server.js file.

Why in the world is there any difference?
For anyone who been down this path, your help would be greatly appreciated.  I have looked high and low, and no solution has yet been found.  What is magic about access through the localhost and not the host name?  I have linked:

```
/var/www/front --> project/src or project/dist and had no luck!
```

This doesn't feel like it should be this hard!  Clearly I don't understand how webpack and webpack-dev-server serve static files.

THANKS!!

---

Aside:
For anyone attempting to solve the cors issues on the server side (the express server) I needed to add this code in my app.js file:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});

app.options("/*", function(req, res, next){
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, x-xsrf-token');
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

This then allowed complete communication from the front-end to the back-end on a different port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The front-end requires additional resources, which it requests relative to the root. You are trying to force it into a subdirectory.

Clearly the URI `/webpack-dev-server.js` works at `//127.0.0.1:3000`, but needs to be `/front/webpack-dev-server.js` when accessed from `//example.com`.

This is a very common problem, and some applications can be very stubborn about being forced into a subdirectory.

Depending on how much control you have over the application, you might consider:

1) Using path-relative URIs rather than path-absolute URIs. For example:

```
src="webpack-dev-server.js"
```

2) Configuring your application to use the correct subdirectory (which will of course break `//127.0.0.1:3000` instead). For example:

```
src="/front/webpack-dev-server.js"
```

3) If this is a single purpose server, move the front-end into the root. For example:

```
location ^~ /server/ {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9000/;
    ...
}
location / {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3000;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your information was quite helpful and it pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks.  I added a proxy at the root, to convert https access to the port 3000 to connect with the front end.  -- and all is now working!  ??? are there any issues with doing a  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;  -- i wouldn't believe so.

Comment: You mean without the trailing `/`? See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details, but substituting `/` for `/` serves no purpose, so leaving it off is slightly more efficient.

Comment: I worked on this issue some more in the case of a HTTPS server and solved another issue that might be helpful to others that follow this post.  For those interested see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081342/webpack-dev-server-with-nginx-proxy-pass-for-https-domain-causes-neterr-conne