# HTTP request for resources (js, css) return a 404 error

Tags: angular, nginx, kubernetes

**context**

I deployed an angular 2 app on my kubernetes cluster on GCE. I can access it using a load balancer service through the public IP exposed without any issues.
However, I intended to access it on the path `/assessment` and therefore set up an nginx reverse proxy with the following contents.

**config**

```
$ cat nginx/frontend.conf 
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/tls/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/tls/key.pem;
    location /assessment/ {
        proxy_pass http://participation-frontend.default.svc.cluster.local/;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

**symptoms**

While the html is rendered, resources (css, js) wouldn’t be found and a `404` would be returned instead. Any idea why this happens?
I also noticed, that if I set the location to `/` instead, everything works perfectly.

**logs**

As you can see in the log excerpt bellow, the request for a file would be performed directly on root. In this case: `/inline.508911a34e3d7fcf458e.bundle.js` instead of `/assessment/GET /inline.508911a34e3d7fcf458e.bundle.js`

```
“/etc/nginx/html/inline.508911a34e3d7fcf458e.bundle.js” failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.132.0.4, server: , request: “GET /inline.508911a34e3d7fcf458e.bundle.js HTTP/1.1", host: “<nginx-public-IP>”, referrer: “https://<nginx-public-IP>/assessment/“
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057099/why-does-angular2-webpack-starter-work-with-localhost3000-but-not-with/43065258#43065258) may help.

Comment: @RichardSmith I'm already using path-relative variables, e.g. `src="inline.21b67490345418068f8f.bundle.js"`. Also, it's not a single-purpose server, since I want to route to several APIs and SPAs from my nginx reverse proxy. So that means, there is really no solution for my scenario?!

Comment: The logs disagree. That log entry  does not appear to be path-relative.

Comment: @RichardSmith maybe I misunderstood your answer. I just checked that in the root html `index.html` the loaded scripts/css files don't point on absolute paths: `<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.21b67490345418068f8f.bundle.js">`. Since both files are located in the same directory, that should work. Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: Are you using `/assessment` or `/assessment/` to access the main page? The path-relative URIs do not work unless there is a path to be relative to.

Comment: I use `/assessment/`: you can even test it on http://35.187.54.121/assessment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [html5 base url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) has to match the location defined in nginx.

- nginx location: `location /assessment/`
- base url in index.html of the angular2 app: `<base href="/assessment/">`